# Autocmd to trigger on Window Select in Ideavim

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim, autocmd

I am trying to reproduce the tips outlined in [this article](https://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/vim-number/) in IdeaVim. Relative or hybrid line numbers work like a charm, no trouble there.

However, when using with split windows in IntelliJ Idea (opened for example by ) I would like to have the split window that currently does not have focus to display absolute numbers while the focused one uses relative numbers.

To see what I mean scroll to the bottom of the linked article.

The article recommends using the following auto command to achieve this result:

```
augroup numbertoggle
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter,FocusGained,InsertLeave * set relativenumber
  autocmd BufLeave,FocusLost,InsertEnter   * set norelativenumber
augroup END
```

However, this does not produce the  desired result when switching between split windows in IdeaVim. I assume that this is because the events, such as `BufEnter`, `BufLeave` are not triggered.

Is this even possible in IdeaVim? If so, how must the above command be changed Is there a list of event supported in IdeaVim?

Comment: Looks like it is not available for IdeaVim. Please try this plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7414-relative-line-numbers

Comment: @audrey displaying relative line numbers work with IdeaVim. I think you misunderstood my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autocmd` commands are not supported in IdeaVim at the moment and there is no feature request about it. Feel free to create a new feature request for it in the issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM. I would consider splitting it into two issues: the one about `autocmd` and another one about `augroup`.